# How to rewrite url with try_files css, js file [ laravel + vue-cli nginx]

Tags: laravel, nginx, vue.js, laravel-5

I'm using vue-cli for frontend and Laravel for backend

Here is my Nginx config:-

```
server{
 // Here I set up laravel in root project
 listen 80;
    root /var/www/html/serverside/public;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name  localhost;

  //Here is vuejs project
  location / {
    root /var/www/html/frontend;
    try_files $uri $uri/ = /index.html;
  }

  //Here is example when I want to use route path in laravel project
  location /admin {
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
  }
 }
```

The Problem is  `assets()` in Laravel redirect to `/var/www/html/frontend;`

How can I make asset in Laravel redirect in `/var/www/html/serverside/public;`

I try to do something like this:-

```
// if enter /admin-js I want to read app.js file but it didnt working
location /admin-js {
        rewrite ^/admin-js/$ /var/www/html/serverside/public/js/app.js;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?query_string;
    }
```

Comment: You do realize that `/var/www/html/serverside/public/js/app.js` is not available to the public?

Comment: @Jerodev yeb I cant enter into that file when I enter to /admin-js